# Define connection pool size in iis 7 (not by connection string)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, database-connection, connection-pooling

So our connection string is constructed from app settings rather than stored as an actual connection string. Stupid I know, was done years before I was here.

Question is, can I do something in the web.config or in IIS itself to define the processes default connection pool from a configuration standpoint so I don't have to change the code that creates the connection string and deploy a new version of the dal to increase the connection pool.

Ideas?

Comment: What DB are you using? And how do you connect to the DB?

Comment: @Remy: MSSQL and using C# ADO.Net, but not using a web.config's Connection string, rather the connection string is constructed by strings in the app itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that is not possible with SqlConnection. But the default value is set to 100. Should that not be enough? Why do you want to increase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done. Connection pool size can be defined only by connection string.